# MediaRecorder implementing setOnInfoListener -max duration

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I 'm using mediarecorder to capture audio through MIC. I have set the max duration to 20 seconds. The recording stops automatically and does not stop at my break point inside   setOnInfoListener.

```
**UPDATE: Changed my code according to suggestion but still doesnt stop at the breakpoint inside the listener.**

mRecorder.reset();
mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {                     
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
            mRecorder.stop();

        }          
    }
});
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
mRecorder.setMaxDuration(20000);
try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
} catch(IOException exception) {
    mRecorder.reset();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
    return;
}
mRecorder.start();
```

Can someone please tell me why does the code not hit my onInfo method inside the listener rather silently stops recording.

Thanks

Comment: Most calls made to mRecorder need to be placed before prepare() but after the setOutputFormat(). If you look at the state diagram for mediarecorder you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the output format, try using THREE_GPP instead of RAW_AMR.

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) for `setOutputFormat()`:

```
It is recommended to always use 3GP format when using the
H.263 video encoder and AMR audio encoder. Using an MPEG-4
container format may confuse some desktop players.
```

Comment: What relation does this have to the question?

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your call to `setOnInfoListener()` before the call to `prepare()`.

In my own video capture code, I invoke `setOnInfoListener()` right after creating the `MediaRecorder` object.  In your code example, a good place might be right after `reset()` and before `setAudioSource()`.

Otherwise, the body of your `OnInfoListener` class looks correct.

I've added the MediaRecorder setup code from my app, which does work correctly.

```
try {
    mCamera.unlock();

    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener( new VideoRecorderErrorListener() );
    mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener( new VideoRecorderInfoListener() );

    // As per Android API docs, the ordering of the following initialization
    // calls is important.
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile( mOutputFilePath );

    mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(VIDEO_MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(AUDIO_CHANNELS);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(AUDIO_SAMPLING_RATE);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(AUDIO_ENCODING_BIT_RATE);
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(VIDEO_MAX_DURATION);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(mPictureFPS);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(VIDEO_ENCODING_BIT_RATE);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);

    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());

    mMediaRecorder.prepare();

    mMediaRecorder.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
```

Comment: that didnt make any difference.  i 'm calling the code above on button click event...does the logic need to be part of a thread or something??

Comment: No, I'm not using a thread for the MediaRecorder setup and it works fine for me.  Two differences between yours and mine: 1) I'm recording video + audio.  2) I defined the listener as an inner class, rather than an anonymous class.  I don't think either of these would make a difference, though.  If I come up with another idea, I'll certainly let you know.

Comment: In the meantime, I added my MediaRecorder setup code.  Maybe you can get something from it.  I know that the order in which you make the setup calls to MediaRecorder is VERY, VERY important.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html "applications are required to create MediaRecorder objects on threads with a Looper running" without it you can't receive info events

Answer (score 0):

as soon as it will reach the maximum duration, it will call the (Customized Method) stopRecording(): Where we can handle all the stop recording and release player camera and preview.

```
 myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
 myRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                    stopRecording();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

u passed the MediaRecorder mr object into your method but you didn't use it. Try mr.stop();

Comment: Hi @Ken, this is not a chatting site. Please be more considerate about the language and formatting of your answers. Formatting your answers beautifully makes it easier to read and has better chances of being useful.